# ASP.NET Manual ListBox Filters for GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, listbox

I have multiple **ListBoxes** as Categories, Departments, Faculties etc. And I have a **GridView** populated from database (**MSSQL**) in code-behind. I will use ListBoxes as **filters**.

For example, when i choose a category from **CategoriesListBox**, the GridView will show only the entries in this category. And when I also choose a Department, the GridView will show only the entries in selected category and department.

I suppose that I will do it by use of **selectedIndexChanged** event of ListBoxes. My aspx code is:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{  
    private string constr = MY_CONNECTION_STRING;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillGridView();
    }

    protected void FillGridView()
    {
        string Query = "SELECT * FROM Entry WHERE Category = '" + SelectedCategory  +"' AND Department = '" + SelectedDepartment +"'";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conn);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Hata: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void CategoriesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Here I want to get SelectedCategory value and re-fill GridView
    }

    protected void DepartmentsListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Here I want to get SelectedDepartment value and re-fill GridView
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by select from your table where CategoryName =@parameter in your connection string

@parameter is your listbox selectedItem or selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Using your own code, why not pass the category and department to the FillGridView? And if one of those are null it would mean no filter at all. So, something like this:

```
protected void CategoriesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillGridView(lbCategory.SelectedItem.ToString(), lbDepartment.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
```

The same would be applied on the `DepartmentsListBox_SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Then change the FillGridView function to:

```
protected void FillGridView(string SelectedCategory, string SelectedDepartment)
```

Also, if I may I'd suggest to gather all the table contents at once, save data to an in-memory copy and filter them from said copy, this would enable a much more fast and better user experience imo.

Edit:

```
            if (selectedCategory.Trim() == "")
            selectedCategory = "IS NOT NULL";
        else
            selectedCategory = " = \'" + selectedCategory.Trim() + "\'";

        if (selectedDepartment.Trim() == "")
            selectedDepartment = "IS NOT NULL";
        else
            selectedDepartment = " = \'" + selectedDepartment.Trim() + "\'";

        string Query = "SELECT * FROM Entry WHERE Category " + SelectedCategory + " AND Department " + SelectedDepartment;
```

Add it to the beginning of the FillGridView function (this is just a quick & easy hack, not the best solution).

Comment: thx, and what should i write for the `FillGridView()` method in PageLoad? (to show GridView without filters)

Comment: If they arguments pass are null you can just remove the conditional part of the SQL query (the WHERE part onward), so you could do something like this (check the edit)

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay I was having problems editing the code, it should work fine now.

Comment: thanks, but i think this will be not an efficient way (as you said). can you please give detail about your previous suggestion (in-memory copy and filter)